# Вживаємо трапляється/ Суперечний переклад слова "трапляється"

Tags: переклад, різниця-між-словами

Розібратися самій у цьому питанні духу не стало...
Згідно з цим джерелом
http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53399/33264.html
Значення слова “зустрічається” (як калька з російської встречается), ми на заміну вживаємо “трапляється”.
Але, якщо перекласти слово “трапляється” на російську то бачимо інше значення слова взагалі - “случается” !
https://translate.google.com/m/translate?hl=ru#ru/uk/%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F

Як діяти в цій ситуації?

Comment: А якого результату ви очікували від останньої дії? Навіщо це слово взагалі після усього перекладати іншою мовою? З якою метою?

Answer (score 1):

Нічого складного тут нема. При зворотньому перекладі багатозначних слів отримуємо часто переклад іншого значення слова.
Беремо багатозначне слово з російської мови "встречаться":

> Значение слова встречаться Ударение: встреча́ться несов.   Сходиться,
>   сближаться, двигаться с разных сторон навстречу друг другу. Попадаться
>   навстречу кому-л., оказываться на пути кого-л. 2) Сталкиваться в
>   противоборстве, поединке, вступать с кем-л. в схватку. Выступать в
>   спортивном состязании. 3) Проводить время вместе с кем-л.; видеться.
>   Видеться с кем-л. для деловой беседы, обмена мнениями и т.п. разг.
>   Быть в близких, интимных отношениях. 4) Наблюдаться, попадаться,
>   бывать. Возникать, случаться. Быть встреченным каким-л. образом.

[Толковый словарь Ефремовой](https://www.efremova.info/word/vstrechatsja.html#.WrIJnmrFIps)

Відповідно до різних значень мають уживатися різні українські слова.

1. Зустрічастися - в сенсі зближатися [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zustrichatysja)
2. Сходитися - коли це в поєдинку [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/skhodytysja)
3. Бачитися - в сенсі близько спілкуватися [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/bachytysja)
4. Траплятися - власне, попадатися, про що було ваше питання [сум](http://sum.in.ua/s/trapljatysja)

Answer (score 1):

За [СЛОВНИКОМ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=38465&page=1200), дієслово *зустрічатися* є цілком природнім і трапляється у творах українських класиків. Тенденція останніх років віднаходити кальки з російської іноді призводить до немотивованого таврування росіянізмами.
Російсько-український словник А.Кримського наводить такі відповідники до рос. встречать(ся):

> Встреча́ть, -ся, встре́тить, -ся – стріча́ти, -ся, стрі́нути, -ся,
>   стріва́ти, -ся, стрі́ти, -ся, **зустріча́ти, -ся**, зустріва́ти, -ся,
>   **зустрі́ти, -ся;** (застигнуть) зу́спі[и]ти кого́, спобі́гти; (итти навстречу) перестріва́ти кого́, перестріча́ти, перестрі́ти кого́;
>   (случайно) здиба́ти, -ся, зди́бати, -ся, поди́бувати, -ся, нади́бати,
>   спотика́ти, -ся, спітка́ти, -ся.
>
> **Попада́ться, попа́сться** –  1)(встречаться, случаться) трапля́тися, тра́питися (редко потра́питися),
>   здиба́тися, зди́батися, сов. спітка́тися, нагоди́тися, луча́тися,
>   лучи́тися, **зустріча́тися, зустрі́(ну)тися**, знахо́дитися, знайти́ся.

Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–

> Сталкиваться, столкнуться – зштовхуватися, зштовхнутися; стикатися,
>   зіткнутися; (спихиваться) спихатися, зіпхнутися, спихнутися,
>   стручуватися, струтити; зштовхуватися, зштовхнути, (диал.) зударятися;
>   (встречаться) **зустрічатися, зустрітися, зустрінутися;** стрічатися,
>   стріватися, стрітися, стрінутися; (случайно) здибуватися, здибатися;
>   (сводиться) зводитися, звести, (мног.) позводити; (наталкиваться)
>   натрапляти, натрапити

Якщо питання полягає у доречному перекладі слова трапляється, то можна послуговуватися дієсловами попадаться, сталкиваться. Якщо про правомірність використання слова зустрічатися, то головне - перевірити значення на відповідність контексту.